# Unable to deploy local files to Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

In the Project->Deployment window I add a local file `..\data\test.dat` and change the remote path to `assets\internal`

Then I deploy the app and with a Button I run the following code:

```
  Memo1.Lines.Add( TPath.GetDocumentsPath ); // first path
  Memo1.Lines.Add( TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath ); // second path
  // try to see if it's in the first path
  s := TPath.Combine( TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'test.dat');
  if FileExists(s)
    then s2 := 'Y'
    else s2 := 'N';
  Memo1.Lines.Add( s2 )
```

and it displays:

```
/data/data/com.embarcadero.TestApp/files
/storage/sdcard0/Documents
N
```

> Where (the hell) is stored the `test.dat` file ?

I found some articles that use variants for the remote path (e.g. `.\assets\internal` or `assets`), but none of them works

> Is there a documentation page in which it is clearly explained the exact meaning of those directories?

Comment: Are you calling `System.StartUpCopy()` at app startup, before trying to access the file?  `StartUpCopy()` copies deployed asset files to the documents folder.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yes ... or at least it is the first line in the Project source code  after the `uses` (and I think it is automatically executed in the begin/end section of the unit itself). In every case also the second question is crucial: where I can find clear documentation about 1) difference between assets and assets\internal 2) how can I access the assets files without copying them (if it is possible) ...

Comment: 1) http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files 2) you can't (easily), that is why they have to be extracted and copied first.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thank you! But the project source begins with  `uses System.StartupCopy, ... ` and at the end of that unit I see `initialization
begin CopyStartUpFiles;end;`; so why the files are not copied ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: finally I was able to deploy on assets\internal (using adb shell I see the files are there); but no way to deploy to external storage using `assets` as remote path in the Delphi deployment window